# Custom middleware not working to keep banned users out

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

so I followed an online guide to be able to ban users on my Laravel application to keep them out, only it doesn't seem to be working for me. I have been looking for hours to try to find what the solution might be, but I can't seem to figure it out. Every time I try to navigate and login with a user that has a is_banned of 1, it just keeps me logged in, instead of getting logged out and not being able to log in anymore.

**CheckBanned.php (middleware)**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckBanned
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {  
        if (auth()->check()) {
            if (auth()->user()->is_banned != 0) {  
                $message = 'Your account has been blocked';        
                auth()->logout();     
                return redirect()->route('login')->withMessage($message);      
            }            
        }

        return $next($request);   
    } 
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\CheckBanned::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
}
```

**Users table migration**

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->boolean('is_banned')->default(false);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

So my question is, has this online guide pushed me in the right direction to add this functionality to my application? Or should I try to find a different solution to add this functionality?

Comment: post your migration file for the users table

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have edited my post with the Users table migration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `CheckBanned` middleware down the list in the `web` middleware group. It's being invoked before the `StartSession` middleware has run.

```
'web' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckBanned::class, <---------------Moved down
],
```

Comment: Thanks that was it!

Comment: Did you mean `after` instead of `before`  the `StartSession` middleware? Furthermore, you could define priorities in the same file with the `$middlewarePriorities` property instead of relying only on the order of the middleware inside the group

Comment: `CheckBanned` needs to be listed _after_ `StartSession`, as it relies on a user to successfully authenticate first. Setting `$middlewarePriorities` could work as well, but in this case it's overkill.